# Youtube Iframe tag stripped on saving

Tags: joomla-3.x, editor, tinymce

For Joomla 3.6.2, Trying to embed video - but iframe tags and the code in it are stripped on saving

Did following
1 Check and removed iframe from prohibitor element in Tinmce editor in plugin settings

2 Check Text Filter settings - its having no restriction for super user

3 No other security tool installed other than akeeba admin tools - no such setting to disallow iframe

Checked field settings - its

```
<field name="n_long_description" type="editor" buttons="true" filter="safehtml" label="NEWS" description="NEWS DESCRIPTION" hint="Detail" required="true"/>
```

Pl advise why is iframe tag been removed on saving

Comment: What happens when you set filter="safehtml" to filter="raw" in you field settings xml?

Answer (score 3):

From [how to add an iframe](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-3/writing-articles/adding-iframes)

> 1. Log into your Joomla 3 administrative dashboard In the top menu,
> 2. click Extensions and then click Plug-in Manager
> 3. In the left menu under
>    Filter, click Select Type and then click editors. In the list of
>    results, click Editor - TinyMCE.
> 4. At the top of the page, click the Basic Options tab
> 5. Scroll down until you find the Prohibited Elements
>    setting: prohibited-elements
>
> **Prohibited Elements**
>
> Elements that will be
> cleaned from the text. Do not leave empty - if you do not want to
> prohibit anything enter dummy text e.g.cms
>
> The default text is
> script,applet,iframe. Delete ,iframe so that the setting now reads
> script,applet
>
> Click Save in the top left menu.

Comment: Hi - this is already tried and referred as step - 1 -  Check and removed iframe from prohibitor element in Tinmce editor in plugin settings. But still when the editor saves it - the iframe code is deleted. using default tinymce

Comment: I removed iframe from tinimce prohibited elements and checked joomla filters - still have the problem!

Answer (score 2):

I am a big fan of the **NoNumbers Sourcerer** plugin.  It allows you to put any type of code into articles and custom modules very easily and the free version will do what you need.  There have been several times that I had done troubleshooting to same issue as you, fixed it, and then some future upgrade broke it again and I lost my code.  This way protects you from that.
https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/sourcerer#sourcerer-description

Comment: Thanks - but not interested in any additional plugin. Is there a way to add on youtube video after removing in iframe tag

Comment: YellowWebMonkey is right! Sourcerer is the best solution to your problem. Its something that should have been bundled with Joomla. Don't make things complicated and use Sourcerer. Its the best out there.

Comment: Sourcerer adds raw code to the database, and as such is an awfully hacky and messy solution.  Professional developments should not use it.

Answer (score 1):

COMPONENT--> JCE EDITOR--> EDITOR PROFILES--> DEFAULT-->PLUGIN PARAMETER then mark "Allow IFrames"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try use JCE editor?

Its free and you can control any tag.

https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net

Comment: no jce, pl advise if possible in tinymce

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set `filter="safehtml"` to `filter="raw"` in your `administrator/components` fields xml.

This setting should allow html tags from the admin editor fields.